# When I use the \setcounter{page}{1} I got a blank page after my preface

Tags: setcounter

When I use the `\setcounter{page}{1}` I got a blank page after my preface but no page number. Is there's a way to remove it ? I already use the `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`  I'm using a re:view https://github.com/kmuto/reviewto generate a latex

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the `\cleardoublepage` is automatic (depends on stuff not shown), then you have `\clearpage\clearpage`.  Remove the first `\clearpage`,

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. We expect each poster provides a minimum working example (MWE) in text, not as a screenshot. MWE consists of `\documentclass[]{}`, preamble and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` block, and is ready to compile. Minimum means you bring only minimal code that demonstrates the problem in question.

Comment: don't show code as an image show a small but complete file in a code block, but your first image shows `\let\clearpage\clearpage` which does nothing at all